# Selecting files from another file that contain string

Tags: python

I would like to select all the files in data_file directory that contain the string that is between first and second underscore in files that are in template_file directory.
For example, in template_file directory there are files:

> Summary_Hamburg_2020.xlsx, Summary_Sydney_2020.xlsx and Summary_Washington_2020.xlsx

In data_file directory there are files:

> Data_Hamburg_2018.xlsx, Data_Hamburg_2019.xlsx, Data_Hamburg_2020.xlsx, Data_Sydney_2018.xlsx, Data_Sydney_2019.xlsx, Data_Sydney_2020.xlsx, Data_Washington_2018.xlsx, Data_Washington_2019.xlsx, Data_Washington_2020.xlsx

So, if file Summary_Hamburg_2020.xlsx is selected then files Data_Hamburg_2018.xlsx, Data_Hamburg_2019.xlsx, Data_Hamburg_2020.xlsx should be printed on screen. If file Summary_Sydney_2020.xlsx is selected then files Data_Sydney_2018.xlsx, Data_Sydney_2019.xlsx, Data_Sydney_2020.xlsx should be printed.

Is it possible to do it with fnmatch? My current solution isn't working.

```
import fnmatch
import os

data_file = "C:\\2020\\New\\"
template_file = "C:\\2020\\New\\Reports\\"  

for filename1 in os.listdir(template_file):
  for filename2 in os.listdir(data_file):
    city = '_'.join(filename1.split('_')[1:2])
    if (fnmatch.fnmatch(filename1, city)):
        print(filename1, filename2)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if this suits you?:

```
import os

data_file = "path1"
template_file = "path2"  

for filename1 in os.listdir(template_file):
    city = filename1.split('_')[1] if filename1.count('_') > 1 else 'Nothing'
    for filename2 in os.listdir(data_file):
        if (city != 'Nothing') and (filename2.count('_') > 1) and (filename2.split('_')[1] == city) :
            print(filename2)
```

This code works on certain conditions e.g in path1 are only templates file and in path2 only data file (meet format text1_text2_text3.extension)

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_ Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works. Could you clarify a bit how this line works: city = filename1.split('_')[1] if filename1.count('_') > 1 else 'Nothing'. Especially: filename1.count('_') > 1?

Comment: `code if condition else code2` - is called inline if statemant in python
The first mentioned line of code assign the part of `filename` between the first and second underscore or `Nothing` The if statemant ensures `filename` contains at least 2 underscores otherwise assign `Nothing` to `city` variable
The interesting about this code is this line `if (city != 'Nothing') and......`
I purposely put `Nothing` in the first condition. If `city` equals `Nothing` then the rest of `if` isn't evaluated